# S3: Console cannot delete events

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have an S3 bucket, registered with 3 events (trigger lambda). I tried to delete one of them, but I receive the error:

```
Unable to validate the following destination configurations. Not authorized to invoke function [arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:xxxxx:function:lambda-test]. (arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:xxxxxx:function:lambda-test, null)
```

The policies in the lambda role:

```
AWSLambdaFullAccess 
AmazonS3FullAccess
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error message is trying to get you to configure your function that receives the event rules properly. You need to use a resource-based policy on the lambda function to allow s3 to invoke the function. For example,

```
$ aws lambda add-permission --function-name lambda-test --action lambda:InvokeFunction --statement-id s3 \
--principal s3.amazonaws.com --source-arn arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-123456 --source-account 123456789012
```

See the docs for more details https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html#permissions-resource-serviceinvoke